# Python initialising objects with kwargs

Tags: python, object, attributes, keyword-argument

I am trying to initialise objects using kwargs and am using the code below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (self.name, self.age, self.address)


a = A(name="J Smith", age=20, address ="New York")
b = A(name="B Jones", age=40, address = "Chicago")
```

My current problem with this method is that it seems to be much slower using kwargs instead of updating the variables individually (i.e a.name="J Smith", a.age=20) instead of passing them as dictionaries. Also after I initialise 'b', I find out that the attributes of instance 'a' have been overwritten with the attributes of 'b'. Is there something I am doing wrong here and/or is there a step that I am missing?

Comment: _"I find out that the attributes of instance 'a' have been overwritten with the attributes of 'b'."_ That doesn't happen on my machine. Can you post some code that demonstrates your problem? Right now, you've got some syntax errors.

Comment: Need more info... if you do `A.name="J Smith"`, you would be setting a _class_ variable, not an _instance_ variable.

Comment: Running this code in Python 3.2.2, I see neither slowness or the attribute overwriting. Could you copy/paste a Python session showing the problem?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman That shouldn't be a problem, as instance attributes always shadow class ones.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, edited the question with the non-syntax error code. But it seems to work now whereas it didn't before, they are 2 different classes now.
Also Corley, sorry it was meant to be a lowercase a so a.name="J Smith", but it still is slower doing it through kwargs then updating variables, but is this the correct format?

Comment: http://codepad.org/Q4cIAbUP works fine.

Comment: Thanks all, it does seem to work now for this example code which was a simplified version of my problem. I thought the issue was related to assigning kwargs so I didn't post the entire class. I will try to see if I can reproduce the error again. Thanks again all for all your help

Comment: Ok so ends up it was overwriting the different instances, because of the way I called them. I had a case of nested classes and it got messy. But thank you so much for clearing up the issue for me, I would not have realised this without your help as I have been staring at this piece of code for over a day and getting nowhere. Thanks and +1 all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that using **kwargs to update the class is almost twice as slow compared to manually setting each variable. However there should be no issues with two separate class objects overwriting one another. Reference:

```
import timeit

class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class C:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def initialize_class_a():
    a = A(name="J Smith", age=20)
    b = A(name="B Jones", age=40)
    return a.name, b.name

def initialise_class_b():
    a = B(name="J Smith", age=20)
    b = B(name="B Jones", age=40)
    return a.name, b.name

def initialise_class_c():
    a = C(name="J Smith", age=20)
    b = C(name="B Jones", age=40)
    return a.name, b.name

print(initialize_class_a())
# ('J Smith', 'B Jones')
print(initialise_class_b())
# ('J Smith', 'B Jones')
print(initialise_class_c())
# ('J Smith', 'B Jones')

print(timeit.timeit("initialize_class_a()", "from __main__ import initialize_class_a"))
# 1.93
print(timeit.timeit("initialise_class_b()", "from __main__ import initialise_class_b"))
# 2.19
print(timeit.timeit("initialise_class_c()", "from __main__ import initialise_class_c"))
# 1.03
```

Notice that in each run the name of the two separate class objects, a.name and b.name, are still reporting to be different.

Comment: Thank you, yes it still is slower but not by much, and yes the instances are different now. I just had a bug somewhere else in the code and I was accidentally attributing it to using kwargs, this code and the comments above helped clarify that, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out! After mention that kwargs was slower I wanted to see for myself so it was a good learning experience for me as well.